# Classic cyberpunk magazine article - not from "Time"

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

I'm in need of help identifying or locating a classic magazine article dealing with cyberpunk (the literature + the aesthetic) and emerging tech - probably circa 1991-1994.

It's *not* [the *Time Magazine* cover article from February 1993](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMdwl.jpg). I'm also pretty sure it wasn't in *Mondo 2000* but rather somewhere mainstream - though possibly *Omni* or *Wired*.

The article in question featured :

1. a really cool 3D artwork by a studio or person called 'The Braid'

- this artwork featured three very different-looking robots standing in an alien landscape
- notable use of texture and lighting (especially lighting direction)
- one of the robots depicted was a kind of bronzy green-yellow, like [Crow from *MST3K*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow_T._Robot)

2. An amusing sidebar on "technodildonics" with humorous male/female images

I've searched pretty intently for this information for about a month, but can't find even a reference to either recalled element (much less the images themselves).

Comment: Note that the term you should be searching for is probably "teledildonics."

Comment: @DavidW: thanks for the tip and edits!

Comment: The Cypherpunk issue of *Wired*, maybe? It was in that time.  Cover had three founding Cypherpunks wearing white masks. I remember nothing of the inside though.

Comment: @AntonSherwood please notice that cy**ph**erpunk is different from cy**b**erpunk, and the question is about the latter

Comment: Sounds right up _Omni_'s...alley.